# unable to install tumbler SDK through pods

Tags: cocoapods, tumblr, tmtumblrsdk

platform :ios, '5.0'

pod 'TMTumblrSDK'

pod install

it showing me the following error

Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a specification for `TMTumblrSDK`

what would be the reason for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Mention process in bit detail what you have done to install this.

Second:

There are Several question related to your query.
please try following link.

> [Unable to find Specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303475/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-privatespec-depended-upon-by-pr)

or

> [Unable to find a specification in CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913733/unable-to-find-a-specification-in-cocoapods)

and for More detail please search on google.

> [Google search Result](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cocoapods%20Unable%20to%20find%20a%20specification%20for)

All in all : there are several possibility to come this type of error. 
like

> [Mokagio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/809944/mokagio) said 
>   You'll need to use the --sources option

and sometime such type of error came due to you have not set master repo correctly. so, suggetion is try to install

> [TMTumblrSDK](https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK)

again with following proper procedure. 
Here is the link

> [How to install cocapods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642692/4910767)