# Editing an existing private cocoapod repository

Tags: git, cocoapods, podspec

A former employee in my company created a private `cocoapod` repo. I downloaded the repo and added code to it. Now I wish to "publish" my changes so that anyone who runs `pod install` will get the new version.

For this task, I followed the guide - [How to Update your CocoaPods Library Version](https://sebastiandobrincu.com/blog/how-to-update-your-cocoapods-library-version)

So, I committed my changes into the master, updated the version to the version number I wish to upload in the `podspec` file, but then, running the verification command fails with the following error: `ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for SalesforceSDKCore (~> 8.0) depended upon by *****`

Here's my `podspec` code:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "some_pod_name"
  spec.version      = "1.0.1"
  spec.summary      = "Summary"
  spec.description  = "Description"
  spec.homepage     = "Some_Homepage"
  spec.license      = "MIT"
  spec.author             = { "My name" => "my_name@gmail.com" }
  spec.ios.deployment_target = "11.0"
  spec.source       = { :git => "git_http_path", :tag => "#{spec.version}" }
  spec.source_files  = "AllFiles", "AllFiles/Core/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  spec.default_subspec = 'Core'
  spec.static_framework = true

  spec.subspec 'Theme' do |ta|
    ta.source_files = "AllFiles/Theme/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    ta.ios.deployment_target = "11.0"
  end

  spec.subspec 'Core' do |ca|
    ca.source_files = "AllFiles/Core/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    ca.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', '~> 3.6.0'
    ca.dependency 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 6.0'
    ca.dependency 'SalesforceSDKCore', '~> 8.0'
    ca.dependency 'ReSwift', '~> 5.0'
    ca.dependency 'PromiseKit', '~> 6.12'
  end

  spec.subspec 'Network' do |na|
    na.ios.deployment_target = "13.0"
    na.source_files = "AllFiles/Network/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    na.dependency 'AllFiles/Data'
    na.dependency 'SalesforceSDKCore', '~> 8.0'
  end

  spec.subspec 'Redux' do |ra|
    ra.ios.deployment_target = "13.0"
    ra.source_files = "AllFiles/Redux/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  end

  spec.subspec 'UI' do |ua|
    ua.source_files = "AllFiles/UI/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    ua.dependency 'AllFiles/Core'
    ua.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 5.0.0'
    ua.dependency 'RxCocoa', '~> 5.0'
  end

  spec.subspec 'Data' do |da|
    da.source_files = "AllFiles/Data/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  end

  spec.subspec 'Storage' do |sa|
    sa.source_files = "AllFiles/Storage/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    sa.dependency 'AllFiles/Data'
    sa.dependency 'RealmSwift', '5.0.0-beta.2'
  end

  spec.subspec 'Analytics' do |as|
    as.source_files = "AllFiles/Analytics/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
    as.dependency 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 6.1'
    as.dependency 'AllFiles/Core'
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is "the verification command"? Do you mean `lint`?

Comment: @matt yes, I mean `lint`

Comment: So, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303475/cocoapods-unable-to-find-a-specification-for-privatespec-depended-upon-by-pr ? In any case, you need to _show your code_. Exactly what did you say, and exactly what was the reply?

Comment: @matt I looked at the link, but couldn't get it to work. I added my code.