# Cocoapods subspec issue: None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency

Tags: ios, github, swift3, cocoapods

I modified a repo on Github to integrate a swift version of my library.

https://github.com/iDevelopper/PBRevealViewController

However when in a new project I try to pod install I get the error:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `PBRevealViewController/Swift (= 1.2.3)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `PBRevealViewController/Swift (= 1.2.3)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

Some helps are welcome!

Please see the Cocoapods issue:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6970#event-1213956994

Comment: delete your podfile and regenerate again once

Comment: This is a new project, then a new podfile!

Comment: check your cocopods is updated or not

Comment: How? By visiting the Cocoapods site? Yes it is.

Comment: check your local cocoapod verson using this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931091/how-to-check-a-version-of-a-cocoapods-framework

Comment: Thank you ! You put me on the way with this link. I have run pod outdated on the terminal. After that run pod install worked! Thanks to Cocoapods limited answer and documentation!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am not familiar this, but I also faced the same issue I followed the few steps

delete your podfile and regenerate your pod file once again use the following steps,

- pod repo remove master
- pod setup
- pod install

Comment: when I run pod repo remove master I get the an error: [!] repo main does not exist

Comment: For me the repo was not `master`, it was `trunk`. `pod repo remove trunk` worked for me.

Answer (score 66):

If you're using Macbook with M1(apple silicon)

Inside your ios Folder follow these commands in terminal

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

If this still don't fix your issue then run

```
 arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this for days until your answer fixed it for me, thank you so much Akaanksh!

Comment: Solved my case. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it for my Capacitor Project.

Comment: I literally spent 3 hours struggling with this until I found this answer! I never thought that it could be related to the OS architecture!! Thank you for this answer!

Comment: The last line of command solved my problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice fix! Spent hours on this issue and only this resolved it. Thanks!!

Comment: Last line did the trick, thanks!

Comment: nice save, forgot about it, but it might be a second time I've needed this trick

Answer (score 18):

You can try to delete `Podfile.lock` And then run `pod update`

Comment: pod update did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with a similar issue for days now and it turned out that the pod that I was trying to include as a dependency is not a valid Repo for CocoaPods I mean the repo is a correct GitHub repo but the problem with it is that it only has a `podspec` in the root of the project and is missing the CocoaPods specs repo structure.
If you read the CocoaPods official guide it might not become obvious what they mean but once I started looking through a specs repo it just clicked.

If you check the example they have given then you will see that you need a different GitHub repo separate from your pod's repo with all the podspecs listed in it. Have a look at their example repo [Artsy](https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git)
You can see what I mean.

What I had as a misconception was adding the source of the single pod at the top of my Podfile, but rather it would have to be the source of a whole specs repo which has to be created separately as I mentioned above otherwise pod install won't be able to find the subspecs as the repo is incorrect.

After the explanation and looking into the Artsy repo I mentioned above I hope that re-reading the [CocoaPods doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html#-add-your-pods-podspec-to-your-repo) will make much more sense as it did to me :)

I hope this helps.

I try to give an example of how the Podfile should look like with the correct source:

```
# The source below won't work if you integrate it as a dependency
source 'https://github.com/iDevelopper/PBRevealViewController.git'
# Instead create a new specs repo as per the info above and include that
# Similar to the one you already have here
source 'https://github.com/iDevelopper/RWPodSpecs.git'
#use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '9.0'

workspace 'PBRevealViewController.xcworkspace'

target 'PBRevealViewController_Example' do
    pod 'PBRevealViewController'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. updating pod version to **1.11.3**
2. Run "pod repo update --verbose"
3. ios / "pod install"

worked for me !!!