# Is it possible to build a release of a Pod from a Branch?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Is it possible to create a pod release from a branch? It seems straight-forward enough from GitHub but `pod install` keeps giving me this issue:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "XXX":
>     In Podfile:
>       XXXY (from `../`) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
>         XXX (~> 2.0.2)
>
> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `XXX (~> 2.0.2)`.
>
> You have either:
>    * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
>    * mistyped the name or version.
>    * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

I’ve tried `pod repo update` and `pod install --repo-update` but it didn’t help.

Excerpt from pod spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'XXX'
  s.version          = '2.0.2'
  s.summary          = 'XXX'
  s.swift_version = '4.2'
```

Release on Github is as below:

[image: Release snippet]

This post seems similar but did not help:
[Cocoapods subspec issue: None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796986/cocoapods-subspec-issue-none-of-your-spec-sources-contain-a-spec-satisfying-the?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Using the source attribute, a CocoaPods podspec can point directly to a tag that can be on any branch like:

```
  s.version          = '5.0.5'
  s.source           = {
    :git => 'https://github.com/Foo/myRepo.git',
    :tag => s.version.to_s
  }
```

Some examples in the podspecs at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk