# Cocoapods: Unable to find a specification for `PUBLIC POD` depended upon by 'PRIVATE POD'

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I keep running into the error specified in the title. I am trying to deploy private pods by this tutorial: https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-swift-frameworks-via-cocoapods-8cb67a584d57 the problem is that the framework I want to deploy has **one** dependency. And due to that dependency I am getting this error, although I have already tried things like: `pod repo update` and also adding `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` along with my private repo source in a test projects Podfile.

My current cocoapods version is 1.9.1.

Comment: Hi @Laurynas, were you able to solve your problem? Most likely you first have to add the private pod source on top of the public pods source. Also if you have a private pod dependency consider not deploying this to the public and only deploy to your private pod spec repository. Regardless your integrator will have to add the private pod source to their Podfile

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If you would post this as a question I would accept it as the correct answer

Comment: done, glad I could help solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you first have to add the private pod spec source (i.e. `pods 'https://github.com/MY_GITHUB_USER/MyPrivateSpecs.git'`) source  on top of the public pods source (`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`).

Cocoapods will first search and resolve dependencies from the private pods specs repository. If unsolved it will search and resolve dependencies in the public pod spec repository.

Comment: Just do add to the answer above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796986/cocoapods-subspec-issue-none-of-your-spec-sources-contain-a-spec-satisfying-the/72714818#72714818