CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "StripePayments"
I have created a react-native project having following dependencies:
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.1",
Now I am trying Stripe Payment Integration in this project. For this I have installed the node package :
"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.37.3",
But when I am trying to do "pod install" I am getting error :
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "StripePayments": In Podfile: stripe-react-native (from ../node_modules/@stripe/stripe-react-native`) was resolved to 0.37.3, which depends on
StripePayments (~> 23.27.0)
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: StripePayments (~> 23.27.0).
You have either:
out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update or with pod install --repo-update.
mistyped the name or version.
not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.`
System details =>
system : macOS Sonoma version 14.4.1
simulator : iPhone 15 Pro Max - iOS 17.2
cocoapods =>
gem which cocoapods
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods.rb
Any ideas??
Please assist me here..
I tried some solutions like :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67803629/1619329
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1116#issuecomment-1312067936

But none of them worked for me.
PLEASE HELP ME INSTALL STRIPE SDK.

Go to the ios directory, delete Podfile.lock file and Pods/ directory and execute pod install --repo-update

I had tried this but it didn't worked for me as there was something wrong with my local environment related to cocoapod version, hence I completely removed and reinstalled cocoapods in my MacBook again

After multiple trials what helped me is to completely remove the cocoapods from my system and re-installed same.
To check the versions of cocoapods installed :
command: gem list --local | grep cocoapods
output:
cocoapods (1.15.2, 1.14.3)
cocoapods-core (1.15.2, 1.14.3)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (2.1)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)

Then to uninstall cocoapods completely, I individually removed each and every package like this
Commands :
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-deintegrate
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-plugins
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-search
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-trunk
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-try

Then I re-installed cocoapods with following command :
sudo gem install cocoapods

After that I installed the stripe npm package
npm install @stripe/stripe-react-native

and install the pod
cd ios && pod install

and finally stipe npm package installed successfully for iOS
