# GitHub CocoaPods conflict with CocoaPod Repository Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods, podspec

Viewing: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

I finally figured out that my CocoaPods project name that I get from "git lib create" isn't guaranteed to be the same once it's eventually added to the CocoaPod repository.

I was testing my podspec dependency, and tried my repository name. I got a lot of code but not mine: *KSFramework*.

```
s.dependency 'KSFramework'
```

But since the following syntax isn't allowed, is the only way to test a Pod dependency via the installed CocoaPod repository?

```
ERROR: s.dependency 'KSFramework', :git => 'https://github.com/ME/KSFramework'
```

This is confusing as the s.source specifies a git repository, but other than Podfile specification, the only repositories available are from the CocoaPods, and not my GitHub files.

```
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/ME/KSFrameworkVersionTest.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
```

I've been looking at various issues between the private Pods (on my computer), the git hosted Pods, and eventually the CocoaPod hosted Pods.

Can someone clarify these issues?
thanks.

one reference:
[How does CocoaPods work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917137/how-does-cocoapods-work/18919959#18919959)

Comment: See https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html

Comment: The manual doesn't explain that private pods and git hosted pods can't be used in Pod development dependencies; only those pushed to the CocoaPods repository. I don't see how these constraint will allow much private or team development.  Yes, I know the Podfile can specify all this, but that is the end use of Pods, not the Pod development. Thanks.

Comment: [private pod dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25759170/5496358) sums up my question as others would like to add their private repository as a dependency for another private pod. Also the [private pods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) doesn't show this either. So again, if private pod dependency isn't available it really limits capability. thanks.